# US Building Codes - Do I need a handrail on this initial section of stairs?

Tags: code-compliance, stairs, carpentry, railing

I realize that building codes tend to vary by jurisdiction, but I'm wondering, in general, do I need a hand railing and/or guardrail on this initial section of stairs as shown in orange?  My hope is that because the section is less than 4 stairs, and under 30" I do not, but I'm not sure if because it's connected to a landing that is connected to other stairs, it requires a continuous railing to the end.

[image: stair illustration]

This is in an accessory building (workshop).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Whether it's required by code or not, it seems like the thing to do.

Comment: I'm looking for a proper building code.  I do see some references to a handrail being required if there are three or more treads in a flight but I don't know how they tie to your jurisdiction.  It looks like this is a substantial project, is a permit required by your jurisdiction?  If so, calling one of the inspectors would be the fastest way to get a legal answer.

Comment: If I came around that corner holding the handrail, I'd expect it to continue. -Securely mounted too, because kids are going to hang on it.

Comment: Thanks all, I understand now that I need to add the lower railing... I've been thinking of it from the perspective that I will be the only occupant 99% of the time, but others will certainly use the space, now or in the future.  Adding the railing is the right thing to do.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: You may wish to add a railing on the other side of the lower portion of stairs, as well. More than likely not required, but just a good idea IMO. Right-handed people may be more comfortable coming down the stairs holding a railing on their right.

Comment: @Aaron: yeah, it's permitted, and has already passed rough, I didn't think to ask when he was in, and was hoping not to bother their office, I know they're super busy.  I think I'll err on the side of over-safe however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [here](http://learnframing.com/building-codes-handrails-guardrails-2012-irc/) from the International Residential Code of 2012.

> **R311.7.8 Handrails.** Handrails shall be provided on at least one side of each continuous run of treads or flight with four or more risers.

I believe you need a handrail since you have at least 4 risers it looks like it could be 5 but your picture cuts off the bottom of the stairs.

Also, the end of the handrail has to return toward a wall or terminate in a newel post or safety terminal.

[This](http://planningandcodes.loudoncounty-tn.gov/documents/constructionExamples/constructionExamples_2012IRCStairHandrailGuardrailConstruction.pdf) site also shows the information in a little more understandable format.

Nice job so far, good luck!